# Getting specific results from multiple tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, row

This is kinda confusing, therefore I will explain my goal step by step, Below are the tables that I am working on (**First Table**, **Second Table**, and **Third Table**).  First, I need to verify if the `username` from the **Second Table** does exist on the **First Table**, if not, remove the one that has no common `username`

The outcome should be something like this (George was excluded since it has no common username to **First Table**):

```
user_id | username
5423    | Bob
43      | Vicky
```

THEN I would like to verify by comparing the previous results above and the **Third Table**. My goal is to check if the `user_id AND username` from the previous results above has a common rows on the **Third Table**, if it does, EXCLUDE that one, and only retrieve the unique ones.

The OVERALL results should be the one below since  `5423    | Bob`  does not exist yet on the Third Table:

OVERALL RESULTS:

```
user_id | username
5423    | Bob
```

**First Table:**

```
| username
| Bob
| Jessie
| Vicky
```

**Second Table:**

```
user_id | username
5423    | Bob
123     | Georgie
43      | Vicky
```

**Third Table:**

```
user_id | username
1       | Luke
54      | Stephenie
43      | Vicky
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443543/create-view-or-use-innerjoins might be of use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    FirstTable a
        INNER JOIN SecondTable b
            ON  a.username = b.username
        LEFT JOIN ThirdTable c
            ON  b.user_ID = c.user_ID 
WHERE   c.user_ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f559/1)

The first join uses `INNER JOIN` so that only records that matches the condition will be on the result list. The second join uses `LEFT JOIN` so that all records from the *left hand side* table whether it has a matching row or not will be shown on the result list. Any non-matching rows will have a `NULL` value on the columns of the *right hand side* table.

Since you want to get only non matching records on the final result, you need to need to have `WHERE` clause that filters `NULL` values on the *right hand side* table.

Comment: First Table does not have user_id, it just a list of username, therefore this line a.user_ID is invalid

Comment: You nailed it! Thanks bro, I appreciate this a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  b.*
FROM    FirstTable a
        INNER JOIN SecondTable b
            ON  a.username = b.username
        LEFT JOIN ThirdTable c
            ON  b.user_ID = c.user_ID 
WHERE   b.`username` <> c.`username`
```